# Passing a string to a function with pointer / C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I want to pass this in my function, but something is going wrong

```
FILE *f = fopen("out.bmp", "rb");
    int countBit = 0;
    int size = 0;
    char* type;

    for (int i = 0; i < 54; i++)
        fgetc(f);
    printf("/* count bit to pixel */\n");
    scanf("%d", &countBit);
    size=DecodeInformationSize(f, countBit);
    type=DecodeInformationType(f, countBit);
    DecodeMessage(f,countBit,size,type);
```

before entering the function type is txt
[image]

but after :

```
void DecodeMessage(FILE *f, int countBit, int size, char* type)
{
    char messageSize[8];
    char nameOut[15] = "outMessage.";
    strcat(nameOut, type);
    char* message = (char*)malloc(size * 8);
```

[image]

please explain problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be absolutely sure we need to know what `DecodeInformationType(f, countBit);` does.

However, it seems it uses some data on the stack. Once it returns, this information may only be available for a few instructions. So your debugger shows that the call to `DecodeMessage`, `type` points to a valid string, but once you enter `DecodeMessage`, the stack is overwritten with the variables of `DecodeMessage`, in particular with `char nameOut[15] = "outMessage.";`

To solve this, make sure that `DecodeInformationType` returns a pointer to memory that is not on the stack (not an automatic variable) of `DecodeInformationType`. That could be memory allocated with `malloc` or a constant string.